# Blender not running when called using php shell_exec()

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, blender, shell-exec

Blender (2.80) is installed on AWS in directory /home/ec2-user.

php is run on the same server from /var/www/html/wed

I have access through cli:

```
wed]$ ls /home/ec2-user
```

Lists contents of /home/ec2-user.

And access through php:

```
<?php<br />
$output = shell_exec('ls /home/ec2-user'); 
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
?>
```

Lists contents of /home/ec2-user.

I can run Blender through cli:

```
wed]$ /home/ec2-user/blender280/blender -b -noaudio proj007/font-sample.blend --python proj007/font-samples.py
```

Runs the blender script (proj007/font-samples.py) and outputs 663 png files to /var/www/html/wed/fonts.

But not through php:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/home/ec2-user/blender280/blender -b -noaudio proj007/font-sample.blend --python proj007/font-samples.py'); 
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
?>
```

Nothing.

Commands are copied and pasted so there is no typo.

Permissions for home, ec2-user, and blender280 are set to allow read and execute.

Is this possibly anApache problem?

Comment: Are you sure the apache user (usually `www-data`) have access to write content into the directory where you assume blender outputs its files?

Comment: User has read and execute access. I don't need to write anything in that directory.

Comment: You write in your question: _and outputs 663 png files to `/var/www/html/wed/fonts`_. That does seem like it needs to have write access somewhere?

Comment: The files are written to /var/www/html/wed/fonts. I know that apache has write privileges to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed php-fpm. It also turns out that I could not get php-fpm to work on AWS using Amazon Linux. Switched everything to AWS using Ubuntu (about a day and a half project) and things are working great.